# How can i get id or value of hidden field from a div which contains a label with class "green2" by javascript or jquery...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple div's having class "questionsDiv" in each div there are three to four div's having class "option" and one of them contains a label with class green2. I want to find the id or value from that div which contains a Label tag with class "green2". How can i get id or value of that hidden field by javascript or Jquery.??

```
<div id="question-1125" class="questionsDiv">
<h3>Question</h3>
<div class="option">
<input type="hidden" class="toId" id="True" value="True">
<label class="pointer" id="3250">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="option">
<input type="hidden" class="toId" id="False" value="False">
<label class="pointer green2" id="3251">Option 2</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(this).find(".green2").prev('input:hidden').val(); this works for me

Answer (score 1):

to select input hidden from try this.

```
$('.questionsDiv .option label.green2').prev('input:hidden')
```

To get value

```
$('.questionsDiv .option label.green2').prev('input:hidden').val();
```

To get ID

```
$('.questionsDiv .option label.green2').prev('input:hidden').attr('id');
```

Comment: i'm using each function $('.questionsDiv').each(function () { if ($(this).find(".option > label").hasClass("green2"))
        {
            alert($('.survey-Question .option label.green2').prev('input:hidden').val());
in first iteration is give correct value but after first it overrides the same value

Comment: $(this).find(".green2").prev('input:hidden').val() this works for me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attr('id')` to get the `id`. Then query with the specific classes want to look in(notice the spaces, references children classes) and then use `prev` to reference the previous element:

```js
console.log($('.questionsDiv .option .green2').prev().attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-1125" class="questionsDiv">
    <h3>Question</h3>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="hidden" class="toId" id="True" value="True">
        <label class="pointer" id="3250">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="hidden" class="toId" id="False" value="False">
        <label class="pointer green2" id="3251">Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to get the id or value of that hidden field that is before the label tag with green2 class as clearly mentioned in my question...

Comment: for example in this html i want to find id or value of this hidden field <input type="hidden" class="toId" id="False" value="False" />